# updating an input dictionary in python

Tags: python

I am defining a function

```
def update(dictionary,key,value):
    dictionary[key] = value
   #  if i do print dictionary... it still shows the original value?
```

I want to update the input dictionary in the main call

So this is the main function i wrote:

```
def update_mapping(mapping_dict,check_word,solution_word):
    #print "here "
    #new_mapping_dict = {}
    for i,ele in enumerate(check_word):
        if mapping_dict.has_key(ele):
            if mapping_dict[ele] == "*":
                mapping_dict[ele] = solution_word[i]

                print ele, solution_word
    print mapping_dict,check_word,solution_word
```

Basically I am inputting a misspelled word and then misspelled word has some mapping.. 
I do that mapping in the dictionary.. 
Like

```
 mapping_dict ={"a":"x"...."s":"*"...}
```

So all the known alphabets whose mapping have been found have a legit key value alphabet pairs..
for the alphabets for which I havent found the right mapping, I am replacing them with "*"
and I am finding them with some algorithm (inverted index)

And as i found those, I want to update my dictionary?

Comment: Show us more context! The code you've supplied so far looks fine (although I personally wouldn't have put that in a function, since it's quite obvious what the wrapped line does).

Comment: More on Cameron, if update dictionary keys is as simple as updating one key-value pair at a time, just do `my_dict[key] = value`, it is more efficient.

Comment: Hi. THanks for comments.. but that was just an example.. I am doing some more checks :)

Comment: I don't any problem. I've ran your code. It did change the content of `s` to something else. See the live example here: http://codepad.org/ACxleA2L   Make sure your intention are correct and you are reading the right outputs.

Comment: THanks everyone. yeah the bug was somewhere else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> test = {"test": 1}
>>> def update(dictionary,key,value):
...     dictionary[key] = value
... 
>>> update(test, "test", 2)
>>> test
{'test': 2}
```

Your problem must be elsewhere - this works.